# XML Parser in OCaml for Windows

Tags: windows, ocaml, xml-parsing

I have found several libraries for XML Parser in OCaml, such as PXP or XML-Light. Anyone knows such a thing that can be used easily in Windows? I found that in XML-Light, they have several `.ml` and `.mli` files, I try to copy it to the `lib` folder of my ocaml, but it doesn't work. Any advice how to do this correctly?

Thank you a bunch.

NB: I don't use cygwin either. I use a MSVC version of OCaml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used [xmlm](http://erratique.ch/software/xmlm) for xml parsing. For simplest installation scenario you can download its distribution and copy `src\xmlm.ml` into your project directory.

Alternatively, you may compile it using:

```
ocamlopt -c xmlm.mli
ocamlopt -c xmlm.ml
```

and put the resulting files into `%OCAMLLIB%\xmlm` directory. Then you can compile your project like this:

```
ocamlopt -I +xmlm xmlm.cmx foo.ml -o bar
```

Comment: @barti: when I did `ocamlopt -c xmlm.ml` why did I always get `Assembler error, input left in file ...` ?

Comment: @zfm: try to compile it with these options `ocamlopt -c -S -verbose xmlm.ml` and post the output

Comment: @barti: `+ ml /nologo /coff Cp /c /Fo"xmlm.obj" "xmlm.asm"
'ml' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
File "xmlm.ml", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Assembler error, input left in file xmlm.asm`

Comment: @zfm: for building native binaries with msvc distribution of ocaml you need ms macro assembler (ml.exe is part of it), see README.win32 from ocaml distrib how to get it.

Comment: @barti: and now I am a bit confused with that macro assembler, when I check ms website, it always brings me into msma 8.0, and it needs visual C++ 2005, but visual C++ 2005 doesn't compatible with windows 7... this is insane, for installing a thing... do you think it's easier to download the mingw version of ocaml?

Comment: @zfm: you can get masm 6.14 from http://www.masm32.com/masmdl.htm (have no idea about its compatibility with win7, though, but at least you may try). And don't forget to add `c:\masm32\bin` to your %PATH%.

Comment: @barti: now it's working and I have .cmi and .cmx finally, where should I put these two files? If I have my ocaml in d:\ocaml, I should put these two files on d:\ocaml\xmlm, right? thank you very much!

Comment: @zfm: nope, they should go to `%OCAMLLIB%\xmlm` (likely it is `d:\ocaml\lib`) and you probably want to put xmlm.o there too. Glad you've managed :)

Comment: @barti: sorry, one more... do you have any example where xmlm is used? I can't find one (I just found the documentation without any simple example)

Comment: @zfm: not at hand, but you can look at http://erratique.ch/software/xmlm/doc/Xmlm (bottom of the page, there are few examples there for a start)